# Passing special characters into mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql

i am trying to pass variables from a list into a mysql table using python. I will get so far down the list untill i receive an eror about a special character. The line of code i am using is:

```
         new_value = "INSERT INTO favs VALUES ( null, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (item1,item2,item3,item4).
```

The first item is the problem,as it has numerous variables with apostrophies in them.
Thanks

Comment: Yup, as @alecxe said, triple quotes will do it `"""SQL"""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the database driver worry about it and *parameterize your query*:

```
query = """
    INSERT INTO 
        favs 
    VALUES 
        (null, %s, %s, %s, %s)
""" 
cursor.execute(query, (item1, item2, item3, item4))
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution above, the escape character in mysql is the backtick ie. `.

So if you wrote this:

```
new_value = "INSERT INTO favs VALUES ( null, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (item1,item2,item3,item4)
```

Change it to this:

```
new_value = "INSERT INTO favs VALUES ( null, `%s`, `%s`, `%s`, `%s`)" % (item1,item2,item3,item4)
```

That's the quick "hack".  The better way is to parameterize it as stated above; but for all intents and purposes, this will work.  The accepted usage is that backticks are used on column and table names.  So if someone names a column key, which is a reserved keyword, you can escape it.